# How can I change text on android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar?

Tags: java, android

How can I change text on *android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar*?
Should I do it in .java?

Comment: Anybody understand you, tell us more details about your problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the toolbar title with this.

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);            
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```